# MiqM.Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.NETCore как подключить элемент управления BusyIndicator в xaml?

Tags: xaml, .net-core

Есть приложение Avalonia Ui под Net.Core.App 3.1. В "window" хочу использовать элемент управления BusyIndicator из [MiqM.Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.NETCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiqM.Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.NETCore/). При использовании xmlns:core="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"выдает ошибку "Ошибка   XAMLIL  Unable to resolve type BusyIndicator from namespace http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit". Пакет MiqM.Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.NETCore подключен через NuGet. Какую ссылку нужно ввести "xmlns:core=", чтобы начало видеть BusyIndicator из данной библиотеки?

Comment: Так это же написано для WPF. Причём здесь Avalonia тогда? Можно конечно адаптировать контролы под авалонию, переписав их. Если контрол простой\, то его можно переписать самому под авалонию заменив специфичные для WPF вещи на те, что аналогичны WPF в Avalonia.

Comment: Посмотрел исходники: https://github.com/miqm/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/BusyIndicator/Implementation/BusyIndicator.cs
Это простейший код, его можно скопипастить и переписать самому под Avalonia.